# errors in making TreeView

Tags: c#, treeview

what's wrong with this code, every time I click on one of the nodes, the nodes will grow, the more I click node then the node will also continue to grow

```
        TreeNode ParentNode = new TreeNode("All Document");
        for (int q = 0; q < Label.Count; q++)
        {
            ParentNode.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(Label[q]));
        }

        ParentNode.ChildNodes.Add(ParentNode);
        TreeViewMenu.Nodes.Add(ParentNode);
        TreeViewMenu.ExpandAll();
```

Comment: What's happening with the code as is?

Comment: when I click on one of the nodes is always a new TreeView appear, can see the pictures here http://postimg.org/image/b4g7pxo33/
there should be no such new TreeView

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are adding parent to a parent. So it has become recursive.

`ParentNode.ChildNodes.Add(ParentNode);`

use some thing like below

```
       TreeNode ParentNode = new TreeNode("All Document");
    for (int q = 0; q < Label.Count; q++)
    {
        ParentNode.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(Label[q]));
    }

    TreeViewMenu.Nodes.Add(ParentNode);
    TreeViewMenu.ExpandAll();
```